# Wpf DoubleUpDown, value rounded automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, rounding

I have a `DoubleUpDown` control (from wpf toolikt) in my window :

```
 <xctk:DoubleUpDown FormatString="F2" Increment="0.01" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding Main.Speed}"></xctk:DoubleUpDown>
```

where `Main.Speed` is a property like :

```
private double _speed;
public  double  Speed
{
    get
    { return _speed;  }
    set
    {
        _speed = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Speed");
    }
}
```

The problem is the value I fill with the keyboard are rounded. If I type `45.2` directly in the `DoubleUpDown` control, my property speed will be set with `45.00` value. If I use the Up Down arrow, everything works.

How to tell the `DoubleUpDown` to do not round my value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, `DecimalUpDown` use the comma. So I have to type `45,2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CultureInfo="en-US" to specify whether using '.' or ',', to avoid further mistakes.
In my case, using a German system I have to use '.'